# jQuery - Remove certain characters from string

Tags: jquery

I have a database inside a custom CMS out-putting plain HTML data.

One of the columns of data has for example the string `2003-07-01T00:00:00.000`

I'm trying to remove `T00:00:00.000` just leaving the date `2003-07-01`.

My attempt is as follows:

HTML

`<span class="dataIssue">2003-07-01T00:00:00.000</span>`

jQuery

`jQuery(".dataIssue").text().replace('T00:00:00.000','');`

**Possible reasons why I think this could be failing:**

My script is wrong.

It takes awhile for the database to load so maybe the script is loading before the database has finished populating on the page (over 3000 records)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the string, you need to apply the change back to the element. And if you have multiple elements, you need to loop over each one.

```
jQuery(".dataIssue").each( function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    var txt = elem.text().replace('T00:00:00.000','');
    elm.text(txt);
});
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(".dataIssue").html(jQuery(".dataIssue").text().replace('T00:00:00.000',''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dataIssue">2003-07-01T00:00:00.000</span>
```